# Can we display property parcel outlines or boundaries on mapbox static map using Mapbox static map API?

Tags: dictionary, static

I want to display the property parcel outlines or boundaries using Mapbox static map API. So I want to know if it is possible to do this using Mapbox static map API. Please Advice me how can we do it.(I am using it in Laravel.)

property address : 30.620948,-86.881137 (10543 JERSEY RD,MILTON,FL,32583)

I want to display the property parcel outlines or boundaries using Mapbox static map API. So I want to know if it is possible to do this using Mapbox static map API. Please Advice me how can we do it.(I am using it in Laravel.)

property address : 30.620948,-86.881137 (10543 JERSEY RD,MILTON,FL,32583)